# Vala for pidgin plugins

Tags: vala, pidgin

Has anyone tried writing a pidgin or libpurple plugin in Vala? From a quick look at the [Vala homepage](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) it seems like it would be a great language for it, and make a good opportunity to learn Vala, but learning both Vala and the fine art of pidgin plugins at the same time is a little overwhelming. Anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Pidgin-Games](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pidgin-games/) is a plugin for pidgin written in vala. You could have a look at its source code http://pidgin-games.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pidgin-games/trunk/src/.
 You probably will want to read the [Vala Tutorial and code samples](http://live.gnome.org/Vala) first if you haven't already.

Answer (score 4):

I also started writing a VAPI for libpurple and I also was able to write a small libpurple client for testing purposes in Vala... So the answer can only be of course! ;)